# Error al intentar abrir un proyecto en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Pase mi proyecto en una usb para transportarlo, pero lo intento abrir en mi mac y me sale el siguiente error:

> android studio will use this android sdk instead

[image]

como puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Manuel, esto no es un error en realidad que afecte a tu proyecto, simplemente al cargar el proyecto se trata de realizar una configuración automática de la ruta del Android SDK para que tu proyecto funcione sin problemas, simplemente da "OK", no temas:)

Answer (score 0):

Como el nombre lo indica `local.properties` son configuraciones locales (de cada computadora/usuario) si vas a trabajar entre dos sistemas diferentes tendrás que tener uno por cada sistema. Es decir en el nuevo sistema lo editas y le pones la ruta correcta del SDK y luego al copiarlo para pasar al otro sistema lo excluis o volves a editarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Si el proyecto que deseas abrir fue creado en otra computadora, la ruta del Android SDK configurada en el proyecto puede ser diferente ya que para instalar el Android SDK, el usuario puede realizarlo en donde desee, por esta razón cuando tratas de abrir un proyecto que fue realizado en otra pc y la ruta del Android SDK es diferente, se muestra el mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**En este caso el mensaje de tu pregunta, indica la ruta de una PC y tu Android Studio de iOS tiene el Android SDK configurado en otra ruta.**

**Si das clic en el botón "OK" la configuración en el proyecto de la ruta del Android SDK se realizará automáticamente.**

Si deseas una configuración manual, abre el archivo `local.properties` y define la ruta del Android SDK de tu Android Studio, que en tu caso sería:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/develophersalpha/Library/Android/sdk
```